# Windows Java File lock when referencing existing file in constructor?

Tags: java, windows, concurrency, garbage-collection, filelock

Suppose I do the following in java for a process that stays open:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
public class LogHolder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file1 = new File("myLogFile.log");        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Running " + new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Have I locked this file in a way that other windows processes can't write to the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).

Comment: He's not really asking about Java semantics here but Windows semantics.

Answer (score 0):

No, you haven't locked the file.  Here's how the Java documentation summarizes the purpose of java.io.File:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames

(In other words, `new File()` doesn't even open the file.)

You can find the rest here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: *"... doesn't even open the file"*.  And doesn't even look to see if the file or its parent directories exist!